# What is abstract for?

Tags: abstract

Could someone explain me what abstract  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Abstract is used for?

I don't see the sense.

Comment: An [abstract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_%28summary%29) is a summary.

Comment: Did you do a test?

Comment: I don't think this question is related to (La)TeX and should therefor be closed.

Comment: Is your question: "Why should I use \begin{abstract}? Why not "\section{abstract}" or "\section*{abstract}"?

Usually, the Abstract stands outside of the structure of a document. Because it is an abstraction of the whole document, it cannot be a part of what it is abstracting. It should stand above the document typographicly and in structure like it stands above logically.

I often see academical papers, made with TeX (and Friends) with a full width-abstract on top and all of its content in two columns. Like this: https://code.google.com/p/pdfsizeopt/downloads/detail?name=eurotex2006.final.pdf

Comment: This question is somewhat ... abstract.

Comment: Thanks Hanseat. That's exactly what I've meant. Why not just using a section for that, but you answered it. Thank you. (add it as response and I will accept it)
And yes sigur, of course I tried out what it does, but I didn't saw the sense in it